# Binary-ish search through partially ordered set

Tags: search-algorithms, binary-search

I have an interesting function.  It takes subsets of {1,...,N} to positive integers, i.e. $f:P([N]) \rightarrow Z^+$.
I know that if S is a subset of S', $f(S) < f(S')$.  Also, if S and S' have the same cardinality, the ordering induced by f is lexicographic, so for example $f(\{1,2,4\}) < f(\{1,3,4\})$.
Given a value *z*, I'd like to find S such that $f(S) <= z$ and $f(S) <= f(T) <= z$ implies $f(S)=f(T)$ -- that is, I want to do a search on the lattice of subsets of [N].

If I knew the ordering were perfectly lexicographic, I'd use a simple binary search.  I don't know that, and I believe it is not (e.g., $f(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})$ is possibly greater than $f(\{7\})$). Is there a good O(N) algorithm to do this search on the poset?  Obviously for N of any appreciable size I have to compute f on-the-fly and can't rely on in-memory storage.

Clarification after a discussion in the comments:
The particular $f$ I am dealing with is additive -- specifically, $f(S) = \sum_{k\in S} g(k) + f(\emptyset)$, with $g$ a monotonically increasing function. This may be easier than the general case (which is also interesting, but not my particular problem).

Comment: There is an O(N^2 log N) algorithm; basically do a binary search on subsets of size K using the lexicographic order, for each K from 0 to N. Retain the one with the best value of f. Can I do better?

Comment: _"the ordering induced by f is lexicographic"_ After sorting the sets I presume? Because $\{1,2\} = \{2, 1\}$.

Comment: Also what is your unit of measurement here. Are queries to $f$ relatively expensive or cheap? E.g. would a hypothetical algorithm that makes $O(N)$ queries to $f$ but takes $O(N^3)$ time in total be preferable to an algorithm that has total time of and makes $O(N^2)$ queries to $f$?

Comment: Yes, lex after sorting the sets.  Think of it this way; if N = 40, I can represent a subset by a 40-bit number, with the highest bit representing whether 40 is in the subset and the lowest representing whether 1 is in the subset.

Comment: Queries to f take O(N) time, but it's independent of the subset, so for N = 40, f({1}) takes the same amount of time as f({1,2,...,39,40})

Comment: If it helps, f is additive; i.e. f(S) + f(T) = f(S\union T) + f(S\intersect T)

Comment: That would imply $f(S) = \sum_{k \in S} f(\{k\}) + (|S| - 1)f(\emptyset)$ and would greatly simplify the problem, can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm (which does mean there is an implementation of f which is faster on average but not indep of the subset). The question is also interesting in the more general case where it is non-additive but that's not what I am currently working on. Easiest to represent $f(S) = \sum_{k\in S} g(k) + f(\empty)$, with $g$ a monotonically increasing function.

Comment: Another question: couldn't there be multiple subsets with the same value(and different elements)?
And thus the search for the $S$ you specified in some cases impossible?

Comment: Fair enough, edited to fix that.

Comment: "Do a binary search on subsets of size $K$ using the lexicographic order, for each $K$ from 0 to $N$".  "Queries to $f$ take $O(N)$ time". Please confirm that algorithm takes $\Omega(N^3)$ time.

Comment: Yes, it does. It takes O(N^2) queries to $f$ -- note that this was before I was asked about time complexity of $f$, which the original problem statement did not address.

Comment: @Craig Will you accept an algorithm that takes $O(N^2)$ time, exactly $N$ queries to $f$ (which is used to get value of $f(1), f(2), \cdots, f(N)$) and $O(N)$ memory?

Comment: John L, if you can show me the algorithm that takes O(N^2) time, N calls to f, and O(N) memory, I'll take it.

Comment: I was trying to writing a rigid specification of the algorithm, which was tiring and unenlightening even though the algorithm is simple. In the end, I just wrote high-level pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that runs in $O(N^2)$ time and $O(N)$ space, assuming that $f(\emptyset)$, $f(\{1\})$, $f(\{2\})$, $\cdots$, $f(\{N\})$ are given in an array.

The starting idea is about the same as what has been given by the OP in his comment. "We will search on subsets of size K using the lexicographic order, for each $K$ from $0$ to $N$. Retain the one with the best value of $f$."

The problem is then how to search the best value of $f$ on subsets of size $K$, named $b_K$, in $O(N)$ time. Instead of binary search, we will check whether $N$, $N-1$, \cdots, $1$ should be included in the best subset one by one, by taking the real advantage of the lexicographic order on subsets.

1. Initialize $b_K = f(\emptyset)$. $\ b_K$ will be the best value on subsets of size $K$ at the end of this procedure.
2. Initialize $count = 0.$ $\ count$ is the number of elements that we have included in the best subset so far.
3. Check $f(\{N\})$. If $b_K + f(\{N\}) + f(\{1, 2, \cdots, K-count -1\})\le z$, $N$ must be included. Add $f(\{N\})$ to $b_K$ and add 1 to $count$.
4. Check $f(\{N-1\})$. If $b_K + f(\{N-1\}) + f(\{1, 2, \cdots, K-count-1\})\le z$, $N-1$ must be include. Add $f(\{N-1\})$ to $b_K$ and add 1 to  $count$.
5. And so on.
6. Until either we have checked $f(\{1\})$ or $count == K$.

We might wonder, if it will take $O(N)$ to compute each $f(\{1,2, \cdots, K-count-1\})$, computing each $b_K$ alone will take $O(N * N)$ time. However, since $f$ is additive, we can compute all prefix sums of $f(\{1\})$, $f(\{2\})$, $\cdots$, $f(\{N\})$ upfront in $O(N)$ time. Then it takes $O(1)$ to access each prefix sum.

Since searching $b_K$ takes $O(N)$ time, for each $K$ from $0$ to $N$, the total running time is $O(N^2)$.

---

The description above of the algorithm skips the easiest case when $f(\emptyset)\gt z$. In that case, the algorithm should return that there is no such subset.

Comment: Modulo minor corrections due to the fact that $f(\emptyset)$ is not 0, this does solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. I just updated answer so that $f(\emptyset)\not=0$ is treated properly.